# How can I fix radio group validation in formk?

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I am trying to get the radio button to show on the console after form submission but I am getting the error message showing up even  an option is selected and I am unsure of what I am doing wrong.

Here is the formik implementation

```js
  const SignupSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    account: Yup.string().required('You must select an option'),
  });
```

```
      <Formik
        initialValues={{
          account: '',
        }}
        validationSchema={SignupSchema}
        // on submit handles here
        onSubmit={(values) => {
          // same shape as initial values
          console.log(values);
          window.location.replace('/SelectProfileType');
        }}
      >
        {({ errors, touched, formik }) => (
          <Form>
            {/* focus form error added here*/}
            <ConnectedFocusError />
            <FormControl>
              <RadioGroup
                aria-labelledby='demo-controlled-radio-buttons-group'
                name='account'
                value={value}
                onChange={handleChange}
              >
                <FormControlLabel
                  value='artist'
                  name='account'
                  control={<Radio />}
                />
                <br />
                <FormControlLabel
                  value='golpher'
                  name='account'
                  control={<Radio />}
                />
                <br />
                <FormControlLabel name='account' control={<Radio />} />
              </RadioGroup>
              <ErrorMessage name='account' />
            </FormControl>
            <Button type='submit' variant='contained'>
              Sign Up
            </Button>
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you have a group that is `account` why do you have an option (`FormControlLabel`) also an `account`? Shouldn't you have only 2 of those for `artist` and `golpher` only?

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue after working on it some more thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue after adding some additional code and tweaking the current base. This is the code that works now. I added an on change handler which helped tracked the change to the radio button which aparently was not being done before. Now if I try to submit the form without choosing an option the radio handler will pop an error message until an option is chosen.

```
const SignupSchema = Yup.object().shape({

  
  account: Yup.string().required('please pick oe of three options'),
}
);

const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');
const [error, setError] = React.useState(false);
const [helperText, setHelperText] = React.useState('Please Choose Whichever Applies');
const handleRadioChange = (event) => {
  setValue(event.target.value);
  setHelperText(' ');
  setError(false);
};

const handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  if (value === 'artist') {
    setHelperText('You selected artist!');
    setError(false);
    window.location.replace('http://localhost:3000/Signup');

  } else if (value === 'golpher') 
  
  {
    setHelperText('selected golpher');
    setError(true);
  
  }
};


const handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  if (value === 'artist') {
    setHelperText('artist selected!');
    // send data to back end here
    setError(false);
  } else if (value === 'gallerist') {
    setHelperText('Gallarist selected');
        // send data to back end here

    setError(true);
  }
    else if (value === 'collector') {
      setHelperText('collector selected');
          // send data to back end here

      setError(true);
        //  show error here if the field is empty

  } else {
    setHelperText('Please select an option.');
    setError(true);
  }
};
```